# Closing a pull request and opening a new one with the same changes

Tags: git, github

I made a branch from our main branch, made changes and now have a PR out there that's being commented on, with me updating it and incorporating those changes.

It's been modified quite a bit and a lot of the comments are now out of date.  I'd really like to close this PR and open a new one, with all of my changes in it.  How can I best do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, I would argue against closing your PR just to open a new clean one to submit all of your changes. PR's are structured to capture the thought process of your feature/fix and your comments (however inaccurate/out of date) represent that process. Additionally, it allows others to have some context with regards to the PR and why you chose to make the changes that you did. In the future, people who see the PR won't know how you decided to make the changes that you did.

If you *really* want to close your PR you can do so by clicking the "Close pull request" button shown below. Then create a new PR merging their working branch with your branch with all of the changes.

[image: Close Pull Request Button]

EDIT:

After you select "New pull request" you can select the *base* branch and the *compare* branch. The *base* branch is the one you cloned, sounds like it was master. The *compare* branch is the one that you made all of your changes to. Once you have specified both branches the changes are compared for you to look over and verify. After that click "Create pull request" to make it official.

[image: New Pull Request]

Comment: I agree with you completely, however that's the way they want to do it.

Sorry, but I'm a little unclear about the steps to make a new PR the way you described?  Do I merge the original branch with mine on github somehow?

Comment: Edited to address your comment